# Array filter returns 0 results

Tags: javascript

Not sure why this is returning 0 when there are clearly 9 with empty strings.

```
function isEmpty(){
  const emptySlots = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '].filter(slot => { slot === " "})
  return emptySlots.length === 9; // emptySlots.length is 0 for some reason
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions have a quirk that takes some getting used to. If you use `{` and `}` then you *must* use the `return` keyword to return a value from the arrow function. In your case the return is `undefined`

So either

```
function isEmpty(){
  const emptySlots = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
            .filter(slot => { return slot === " "})
  return emptySlots.length === 9; // emptySlots.length is 0 for some reason
}
```

or

```
function isEmpty(){
  const emptySlots = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
            .filter(slot => slot === " ")
  return emptySlots.length === 9; // emptySlots.length is 0 for some reason
}
```

Comment: oh I've used them, I'm just blind today and needed another set of eyes thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `{}` in your arrow mean a function body and you aren't returning anything in that function body.

```
slot => { slot === " "})
```

is the same as

```
function(slot){
   slot === " ";
   // No return
}
```

Consider [MDN Arrow Functions - Function Body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body):

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the
>   explicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit
>   `return` statement.

You want:

```js
function isEmpty() {
  const emptySlots = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
    .filter(slot => slot === " ")
  return emptySlots.length === 9;
}

console.log(isEmpty()); // true
```

Comment: oh wow I'm blind today thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for your `sort()` function you have two possible sintaxis

```
.sort(vars => statement);

.sort(vars => {
  return statement
})
```

So when you added `.sort(vars => {statement});` the function is expecting a return value. Whe you dont include them, the function assumes the first line as the return.

Hope this helps:)

```js
function isEmpty(){
  const emptySlots = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '].filter(slot => slot === " ")
  return emptySlots.length === 9; 
  // emptySlots.length is 0 for some reason 
}

console.log(isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply return like:

```
arr.filter(slot => slot === " ")
```

You can also do:

```
const isEmpty=()=>Array.from(new Array(9),()=>' ').filter(s => s === " ").length === 9;
```